# Google Play Billing Library - Free trial not enabled for Subscriptions in India Region

Tags: android, subscription, play-billing-library

I am using the Google Play Billing library system to make subscriptions inside my app. I am trying to do in-app billing/purchase and test my application on an Android Emulator device. I would like to perform some functional testing of my application on multiple emulator devices. Later on, i will test the 'in-app billing' feature on a real device.

I have created a new GMail account and log-in into the play store present in the android emulator device. Every time when i try to purchase a subscription , **a free trial is not being provided**. It is simply saying that "**You've already participated in the free-trial**" . Please check the screenshot below

[image]

When i proceed with purchase of the subscription then it is getting auto-renewed correctly.

Can you please tell me how can a free trial gets enabled for Subscriptions in India region?