# Why Google Play won't show "You're not eligible for a free trial" message for a non-eligible user?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-subscription

[image]I've seen a lot of questions like "Why am I seeing 'You're not eligible for the free trial' message?". But mine is the opposite. I should be seeing this message and I don't.

So, I have 2  in-app subscriptions with special offers:

- a yearly subscription with a free trial offer (eligibility criteria: "never had this subscription")
- a monthly subscription with an introductory price offer (same eligibility criteria: "never had this subscription")

I am a licensed internal tester and downloaded a test build from an internal link.

If a user is not eligible for an intro price, **there is an explanation** in a Google Play purchase widget that says **"You're not eligible for the intro price"**. (see the screenshot).
**However, if a user is not eligible for a free trial, there is no explanation provided**. (see the screenshot)

I don't understand why there's no text info "You're not eligible for the free trial". Performing an eligibility testing I got really confused here. This could also be confusing to a real user.

At first I thought that "You're not eligible for the free trial" does not appear, because free trial special offer isn't configured. As proof that a free trial exists for the offer, I have attached a screenshot showing how an eligible user sees the purchase widget. There's a 3-minute free trial and everything looks good. Then I thought that it had something to do with the chosen eligibility criteria, but they turned out to be the same for both offers. So the only difference between offers is that one of them is a trial offer and the other is an introductory price offer.

Comment: Did you resolve this, for me the trial doesnt show at all.

Comment: No, I still don't see it. However, I came across some screenshots from 2021-2022 where "You’re not eligible for a free trial" was reproduced. In May 2022 a major update of both subscriptions and special offers structure was released in the 5.0 version of the Google Play Billing library. My best guess is that changes in trial non-eligibility handling are related to this release and "You're not eligible for a free trial" isn't the expected behavior anymore. 
5.0 Release notes: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/release-notes#5-0

Comment: Screenshots I'm talking about:
1)https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69395079/google-play-billing-library-free-trial-not-enabled-for-subscriptions-in-india
2) https://community.revenuecat.com/sdks-51/native-android-free-trial-not-showing-in-payment-sheet-2176
3)https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/99971

Comment: It's important to note that, you should still see a trial if you're eligible. Check out this article on free trial test strategy and, please, don't hesitate to reach out if you have any questions. 

https://medium.com/brickit-engineering/test-strategy-for-free-trials-and-introductory-prices-in-google-play-8e0e6a0fdf41